# HDLBits edge detect question about how to update the edge state

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying Verilog practice on HDLBits about edgedetect.
But, I'm confused and can't understand the different behavior between using `if ({d_last, in} == 2'b01)` and `pedge <= in & ~d_last` ?
Aren't they just same behavior to compare the previous and current signal?

**My answer:**

```
module top_module (
    input clk,
    input [7:0] in,
    output [7:0] pedge
);
    
    reg [7:0] d_last;   
            
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        d_last <= in;           
        if ({d_last, in} == 2'b01)
            pedge <= 1;
        else
            pedge <= 0;
    end

endmodule
```

**Warning message:**

> Warning (13024): Output pins are stuck at VCC or GND

This warning says that an output pin never changes (is "stuck"). This can sometimes indicate a bug if the output pin shouldn't be a constant. If this pin is not supposed to be constant, check for bugs that cause the value being assigned to never change (e.g., `assign a = x & ~x;`).

**HDLBits Solution:**

```
module top_module(
    input clk,
    input [7:0] in,
    output reg [7:0] pedge);
    
    reg [7:0] d_last;   
            
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        d_last <= in;           // Remember the state of the previous cycle
        pedge <= in & ~d_last;  // A positive edge occurred if input was 0 and is now 1.
    end
    
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HDLbits solution is bitwise over each of the 8 bits of `in`. If you wanted to take your approach with an `if` statement, you would need to iterate over each of the 8 bits.

```
module top_module (
    input clk,
    input [7:0] in,
    output logic [7:0] pedge
);
    
    logic [7:0] d_last;   
            
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        d_last <= in;
      foreach(in[i])           
        if ({d_last[i], in[i]} == 2'b01)
          pedge[i] <= 1;
        else
          pedge[i] <= 0;
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is very different from the HDLBits solution.  A more verbose way to write your `if/else` is:

```
    if ({d_last, in} == 2'b01)
        pedge[7:0] <= 8'b0000_0001;
    else
        pedge[7:0] <= 8'b0000_0000;
```

As you can see, the 7-bit vector `pedge[7:1]` is always `7'b0000_000`.  7 bits of `pedge` are always 0.  This is the reason for the warning message.

Also, your `if` condition probably does not do what you think it does.  Written another way is:

```
    if ({d_last[7:0], in[7:0]} == 2'b01)
```

You have a bit-width mismatch: the LHS is 16 bits, but the RHS is only 2 bits.  It compares:

```
{d_last[7:0], in[7:0]}
```

to:

```
16'b0000_0000_0000_0001
```